# Matching characters at various levels and generating scores

Tags: r

I have results from two test groups (each group tested the same samples) and I want to evaluate the similarities and differences between the two sets of results. I want to score different levels of matching, from 1 to 4, between the 2 sets of results. For each sample there are paired results separated by a '+'. If both results are identical I want the score to be 1, if they match but are ambiguous (denoted by '/') for one or the other gene the score is 2, score 3 = if group 1 has an ambiguous result, but group 2 is non-ambiguous but they share a gene, score 4 = if group 2 has an ambiguous result, but group 1 is non-ambiguous but they share a gene, score 0 = no match i.e. results from both groups do not share any gene sequence.

```
Group1                            Group2                             Match
Y*01:01+Y*01:01                   Y*01:01+Y*01:01                    1
Y*01:03+Y*01:01                   Y*01:01+Y*01:03                    1
Y*01:01:02+Y*01:01:01             Y*01:01:02+Y*01:01:01              1
Y*01:01/Y*01:02+Y*01:01           Y*01:01/Y*01:02+Y*01:01            2
Y*01:01/Y*01:02+Y*01:01/Y*01:02   Y*01:01/Y*01:02+Y*01:01/Y*01:02    2
Y*01:01/Y*01:02+Y*01:01           Y*01:02+Y*01:01                    3
Y*01:03+Y*01:01                   Y*01:03/Y*01:06+Y*01:01            4
Y*01:01+Y*01:02                   Y*01:03+Y*01:04                    0
Y*01:01/Y*01:02+Y*01:01/Y*01:02   Y*01:03/Y*01:04+Y*01:06/Y*01:06    0
```

I've tried the following formula but it gives me an overall 'true' score for matching, and 'false' for no match. I don't know how to adapt it to generate different levels of matching

```
 df = as.data.frame(mapply(function(x,y) all(x==y),   
 lapply(strsplit(df$`group1`, "[+]"), sort), 
 lapply(strsplit(df$`group2`, "[+]"), sort)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a way to better vectorize it, but if you can accept doing it row-wise then here's a suggestion. (If you're dealing with "large" amounts of data, this might be slow for you.) (Data is below.) (**Edit**ed to deal with an added comparison.)

```
gene_compare <- function(a,b) {
  sa <- sort(strsplit(a, "[+]")[[1]])
  sb <- sort(strsplit(b, "[+]")[[1]])
  if (all(sa == sb)) {
    if (any(grepl("/", c(a,b)))) return(2L) else return(1L)
  } else if (all(mapply(function(m,n) any(m == n), strsplit(sa, "/"), sb))) return(3L)
  else if (all(mapply(function(m,n) any(m == n), sa, strsplit(sb, "/")))) return(4L)
  else if (any(sa == sb)) return(5L)
  else return(0L)
}

mapply(gene_compare, dat$Group1, dat$Group2, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
#  [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 0 0 5
```

And if you use/prefer `tidyverse` verbs:

```
dat %>%
  mutate(Match2 = purrr::map2(Group1, Group2, gene_compare))
#                             Group1                          Group2 Match Match2
# 1                  Y*01:01+Y*01:01                 Y*01:01+Y*01:01     1      1
# 2                  Y*01:03+Y*01:01                 Y*01:01+Y*01:03     1      1
# 3            Y*01:01:02+Y*01:01:01           Y*01:01:02+Y*01:01:01     1      1
# 4          Y*01:01/Y*01:02+Y*01:01         Y*01:01/Y*01:02+Y*01:01     2      2
# 5  Y*01:01/Y*01:02+Y*01:01/Y*01:02 Y*01:01/Y*01:02+Y*01:01/Y*01:02     2      2
# 6          Y*01:01/Y*01:02+Y*01:01                 Y*01:02+Y*01:01     3      3
# 7                  Y*01:03+Y*01:01         Y*01:03/Y*01:06+Y*01:01     4      4
# 8                  Y*01:01+Y*01:02                 Y*01:03+Y*01:04     0      0
# 9  Y*01:01/Y*01:02+Y*01:01/Y*01:02 Y*01:03/Y*01:04+Y*01:06/Y*01:06     0      0
# 10           Y*02:01:01+Y*02:01:01           Y*02:01:01+Y*02:01:50     5      5
# >
```

The performance-hit comes in two forms: operating row-by-row; and nested (repeated) `mapply` calls.

---

Data:

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
Group1                            Group2                             Match
Y*01:01+Y*01:01                   Y*01:01+Y*01:01                    1
Y*01:03+Y*01:01                   Y*01:01+Y*01:03                    1
Y*01:01:02+Y*01:01:01             Y*01:01:02+Y*01:01:01              1
Y*01:01/Y*01:02+Y*01:01           Y*01:01/Y*01:02+Y*01:01            2
Y*01:01/Y*01:02+Y*01:01/Y*01:02   Y*01:01/Y*01:02+Y*01:01/Y*01:02    2
Y*01:01/Y*01:02+Y*01:01           Y*01:02+Y*01:01                    3
Y*01:03+Y*01:01                   Y*01:03/Y*01:06+Y*01:01            4
Y*01:01+Y*01:02                   Y*01:03+Y*01:04                    0
Y*01:01/Y*01:02+Y*01:01/Y*01:02   Y*01:03/Y*01:04+Y*01:06/Y*01:06    0
Y*02:01:01+Y*02:01:01             Y*02:01:01+Y*02:01:50              5')
```

Comment: Excellent both approaches worked well with my large data set. I came across another scenario where group1= Y*02:01:01+Y*02:01:01, group2 = Y*02:01:01+Y*02:01:50, they match for one gene therefore the code should not be zero. I want to call this level of 'half' matching code 5. I know I have to alter the gene_compare function but how?

Comment: See my edit, I think it addresses your additional constraint.

Comment: One last question I've been reading about if else statements and I edited the script to include another level so I could track non-tested samples this worked fine (code 6). However when I attempted to add two conditions to an else if statement (code 7) it produced any error because I'm attempting to apply a non-function. I want to track samples that have "/" in one group plus share identical gene copies.

Comment: Here is the troublesome line: else if (all(mapply(function(m,n) any(m == n), sa, strsplit(sb, "/") $ any(sa == sb)))) return(7L)

Comment: The complete script: gene_compare <- function(a,b) {
  sa <- sort(strsplit(a, "[+]")[[1]])
  sb <- sort(strsplit(b, "[+]")[[1]])
  if (all(sa == sb)) {
    if (any(grepl("/", c(a,b)))) return(2L) else return(1L)
  } else if (all(mapply(function(m,n) any(m == n), strsplit(sa, "/"), sb))) return(3L)
  else if (all(mapply(function(m,n) any(m == n), sa, strsplit(sb, "/")))) return(4L)
  else if (any(sa == sb)) return(5L)
  else if (any(grepl("NT", c(a,b)))) return(6L)
  else if (all(mapply(function(m,n) any(m == n), sa, strsplit(sb, "/") $ any(sa == sb)))) return(7L)
  else return(0L)
}

Comment: This part of your code does not make sense to me: `strsplit(sb, "/") $ any(sa == sb)`. Does the logic hold if you remove `$ any(sa==sb)`?

Comment: It returns that error because it looks at the return value of `strsplit` (a list) for something names `any` (which returns `NULL`), then tries to call that as a function. This means ultimately it is trying to do `NULL(sa == sb)` which is (obviously?) not going to work.

Comment: Yes the logic holds when I remove    $ any(sa==sb)